# My elements in a menu seem to have no width?

Tags: css

see this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLFcn/) for a demo

**EDIT** of course, hard coding a width for an element is no solution. It should be just the size of the actual title.

HTML

```
<br/>

<nav class="navigation">
     <div class="navfake"></div>
            <div class="singleelement">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">Test title 2</div>
        <div class="titlepicture">some picture</div>
    </div>
</div>
            <div class="singleelement">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">Test title newsfeed super long 1</div>
        <div class="titlepicture">some picture</div>
    </div>
</div>
    </nav>
```

css

```
/** the newsfeed and footer */
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.navfake {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}

.singleelement {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
    -o-transition: all .8s ease;
    transition: all .8s ease;
    height: 200px;
}

.titlepicture {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container:hover {
    top: -80px;
}

.container:hover .titlepicture {
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 10;

}

.title {
    z-index: 555;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Be wary using `position:absolute`, this attribute removes the element from the normal document flow. Without positioning it will default to the top left of their most recent DOM ancestor with `position:relative`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The trick was to replace position absolute with position relative](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nbAGy/)

HTML

```
<nav class="navigation">
     <div class="navfake"></div>
            <div class="singleelement">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">Test title 2</div>
        <div class="titlepicture">some picture</div>
    </div>
</div>
            <div class="singleelement">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">Test title newsfeed super long 1</div>
        <div class="titlepicture">some picture</div>
    </div>
</div>
    </nav>
     <div class="footer">some text blablablablablablabla
          <br/>some text blablablablablablabla
          <br/>some text
          <br/>some text
          <br/>some text
          <br/>some text
          <br/>some text
          <br/>xxx
      </div>
```

CSS

```
/** the newsfeed and footer */
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}

.navfake {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}

.singleelement {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    top: -20px;
    position: relative;                 /**changed*/
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
    -o-transition: all .8s ease;
    transition: all .8s ease;
    height: 200px;
}

.titlepicture {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container:hover {
    top: -80px;
}

.container:hover .titlepicture {
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 10;

}

.title {
    z-index: 555;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On `.singleelement` add some sort of width to it. For example `64px` and it will work.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7WZk5/

Comment: ah wait... this is just a patchwork you are recommending there. 64 px is just about the size of the first element. If you add a third, they will overlap again

Comment: @Toskan Not 100% sure myself though when inspecting it, `.singleelement` had no width at all so when you declare `100%` on the children, it has nothing to set 100% of.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for: http://codepen.io/aytimothy/pen/mlkAh

Have you tried adding the "width:" CSS into your "container" Class?

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
    -o-transition: all .8s ease;
    transition: all .8s ease;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Well, 50% since you have two elements. If you want to have different widths for each of them, you could always put the width as a STYLE attribute for each element.

Comment: the problem these elements come from a cms. There is no way to manually set them since they get generated. Might be 2, 1, 10, percentages don't help too much there